# AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python. Could anyone help me with the situation below?
I am running Jupter in Pycharm.
Code are as below.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
amd = yf.Ticker("AMD")
amd_share_price_data = amd.history(period="max")
amd_share_price_data.head()
```

And there is any error, AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'.
For detail of the error, please find below.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 amd_share_price_data = amd.history(period="max")
      2 amd_share_price_data.head()

File ~/PycharmProjects/JupterProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yfinance/base.py:279, in TickerBase.history(self, period, interval, start, end, prepost, actions, auto_adjust, back_adjust, proxy, rounding, tz, timeout, **kwargs)
    276 df["Stock Splits"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    278 # index eod/intraday
--> 279 df.index = df.index.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(
    280     data["chart"]["result"][0]["meta"]["exchangeTimezoneName"])
    282 if params["interval"][-1] == "m":
    283     df.index.name = "Datetime"

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for your comment. 
Could you advise how should I revise my code?
I just want to simply get the share price of AMD.

Comment: What is df? `df.index = df.index.tz_localize("UTC")` Is the index of `df` a datetime object `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`?

Comment: I have no idea, I only wrote those 2 import and 3 amd code.
Those df is from the error message.
I saw some ppl saying it is because of the version of pandas,  I have tried to downgrade it, however the issue is still there.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: I have edited the question above. Please help take a look again. 
Thank you very much, Chris!

Comment: It looks like you need to downgrade pandas (assuming you are pandas 1.4) based on this [github issue](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/939)

Comment: Chris, after downgrading pandas to 1.3.5, there is still the same issue.
Any other workaround?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue when downgrading pandas. Your code runs without error for me in pandas 1.3.5. Make sure you are in the correct environment in pycharm. You can also print the pandas version just to double check: `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: You can also try upgrading `yfinance` to the current version. `yfinance 0.1.70` works with pandas 1.4.2 for me.

Comment: Chris, it works! Thank you very much!
I only downgraded in the environment under the anaconda.navigator, and I thought I would also affect the Pycharm.